# Ruby regex to capture any string with a number

Tags: ruby, regex

I am looking for a regular expression in Ruby to capture a sentence that has any sort of number in it.

For instance, I need to capture all of the following:

- "5 different ways to do it"
- "2 x 2 is certainly 4"
- "there are 15 different things"
- "Try to get to 10"

I only want to capture sentences with a number within, but that has nothing else before or after the number. I don't want to include things like:

- "$2 billion dollars"
- "The 5x effect"

It has to be just a sequence for 1 or more numbers at the beginning, middle, or end of a sentence.

Thanks.

Comment: http://regular-expression.info

Comment: What about `3, ~3, !3, $3, %3, ^3, ..., 3., 3,, 3?, ... and a lot more; are they to be captured? You haven't made clear at all your conditions.

Comment: What if it has both: "The 5 5x effects"

Comment: Sorry - I realize there are a potential lot of conditions.

Comment: @sawa - nothing like the sorts - no special characters around the number.

Comment: @pguardiario - what you've expressed would be OK because it has a plain number within.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want something like:

```
/^.*(?<!\S)\d+(?!\S).*$/
```

Which will match a number and "look-around" for a non-space.

Comment: This seems to work very nicely. Thanks very much! I will tweak as needed, if need be. Just needed a head start here.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
(s =~ /(^|\s)\d+(\s|$)/) ? s : nil
```

will return the string `s` if it contains at least one non-negative integer, that is:

- the entire string,
- at the beginning of the string followed by a whitespace character,
- at the end the string preceded by a whitespace character, or
- is both preceded and followed by a whitespace character.

Comment: This doesn't capture the string.

Comment: Thanks, @ pguardiario.  Fixed.

Comment: Np. `\b` doesn't work because there's a `\b` between `$` and `2` in `$2`

Comment: pg, not going well for me this evening.  I rolled back to what I started with, adjusted to return the string if the regex matches.  Thanks.